# Please stop proposing tag name edits without first doing community discussion on tag names

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

We have plenty of time to discuss what tags we want to have and what they will be called without someone unilaterally creating a consensus through a flood of edits. This could do more harm than good if we decide to do something as a community that's counter to what you thought would be best when you edited the post.

Comment: It seems like it's better to me to fix problems as they show up rather than create a mess that will need to be cleaned up later, but whatever, and yes, I will stop retagging.

Comment: @pppery It's fine to do that yeah, but it should be with community involvement, not just going and editing stuff. That way we can work out together what the best option is (plus it's a CYA and if we end up deciding something dumb, it's on the community as a whole not on just you).

Comment: They are being proposed, and approved

Answer (score 1):

Quite the contrary, the early beta is a good time to do plenty of tag edits! When questions are badly tagged (missing a tag that should be present, using tags with different names but the same meaning, using the same tag name with different meanings, etc.), it becomes harder to fix as the number of questions increases. So retag early, retag often!

If you aren't sure about what tags are appropriate, open a question on meta about the specific tag (or group of closely-related tags).

Comment: Yeah no, my problem isn't with genuinely good fixes, it's with a consensus being unilaterally created on what tags should exist and what they should be called by editing away all the alternatives without prior discussion.

Comment: yeah before the title edit, it might not have been clear, but I'm pretty sure what you're saying here just captures what the question post was already saying (or trying to communicate)- particularly your last point on meta discussion.